# NESTED SELECT QUERY WITH CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, case

Please have a look at the query. 
The issue I am facing is this: 
The **FROM_LOCATION**,**TO_LOCATION** in THEN clause needs to be the value from B_TARIFFS, However when I prefix it with `B_TARIFFS.FROM_LOCATION` and `B_TARIFFS.TO_LOCATION` , I get an error that `ORA-00904: Invalid identifier.`.
If it is available in `ELSE` clause then why cant I use it in the `THEN` clause. What can I do to get my desired result. 
The result I want from the query is this: Get from_location,to_location, tariff (based on case from another table). I am expecting that the Outer query will pass its FROM_LOCATION,TO_LOCATION to the inner select queries in `CASE ELSE THEN`, and based on that a tariff value would be returned which will be the third column of the outer query. What can I do to achieve this.

```
select FROM_LOCATION, TO_LOCATION,

        case when (
            select  tariff A_tariff where A_tariff.FROM_LOCATION = B_TARIFFS.FROM_LOCATION AND A_tariff.TO_LOCATION = 
            B_TARIFFS.TO_LOCATION AND TO_DATE(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')   between TO_DATE(from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(to_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            and rownum = 1
        ) = ''  
        then  

        (SELECT TARIFF FROM (
        SELECT * FROM A_TARIFF WHERE TRIM(A_TARIFF.FROM_LOCATION) = TRIM(**FROM_LOCATION**) AND 
        TRIM(A_TARIFF.TO_LOCATION) = TRIM(**TO_LOCATION**) ORDER BY A_TARIFF.FROM_DATE DESC 
        ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1) 

        else 

        (select  tariff from A_tariff where A_tariff.FROM_LOCATION = B_TARIFFS.FROM_LOCATION AND A_tariff.TO_LOCATION = 
        B_TARIFFS.TO_LOCATION AND TO_DATE(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')   between TO_DATE(from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(to_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        and rownum = 1) end tariff

        FROM B_TARIFFS
        WHERE FROM_LOCATION LIKE '%ABC%' AND AREA_CODE = 'X' ORDER BY TARIFFS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the double nesting.

Why don't you change:

```
    (SELECT TARIFF FROM (
    SELECT * FROM A_TARIFF WHERE TRIM(A_TARIFF.FROM_LOCATION) = TRIM(**FROM_LOCATION**) AND 
    TRIM(A_TARIFF.TO_LOCATION) = TRIM(**TO_LOCATION**) ORDER BY A_TARIFF.FROM_DATE DESC 
    ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

with

```
    SELECT TARIFF FROM A_TARIFF WHERE TRIM(A_TARIFF.FROM_LOCATION) = TRIM(B_TARIFFS.FROM_LOCATION) AND 
    TRIM(A_TARIFF.TO_LOCATION) = TRIM(B_TARIFFS.TO_LOCATION) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    ORDER BY A_TARIFF.FROM_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something like this, now I can access the columns of outer query , so basically the subquery doesn't know about outer select query columns. Isn't there any other way to get them inside the subquery ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @alexandergs the cause of the error is too deep nesting of subquery. But you have bigger problems than that. 
In your `when` clause you make decision depending on some random row, because there is condition `rownum=1` without ordering. 
The same is in `else` clause. Also it is not clear what this `when (select ...) = ''` means - I suspect that you want to show something not empty,
but current construcion does not provide this. You have to rebuild your query to something like here:

```
select b.from_location, b.to_location, a.tariff, b.tariffs, 
    row_number() over (partition by b.from_location, b.to_location 
                           order by a.from_date desc) rn
  from b_tariffs b
  left join a_tariff a 
         on a.from_location = b.from_location and a.to_location = b.to_location
         and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(a.from_date) and trunc(a.to_date) 
  where b.from_location like '%ABC%' and b.area_code = 'X' order by b.tariffs;
```

... eventually add some more code for row_number() - so it sorts rows depending on your needs and take rows with RN = 1.

Comment: Alex's answer solved the issue, however I wonder why doesnt it allow me to access outer query columns inside nested subqueries, And yes,I changed  `when (select ...) = ''` to `case when ( .. ) is null`, now query is working. Thanks.